# DatePicker Today button not displaying

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a datepicker with the below code. But when I set my system date to less than the server date (for ex: changed my system date to 1 day prior), Today button is not displaying and the html markup in the Developer Tool is not showing Today button completely (Attached the markup of the datepicker buttons below). If both the system date and the sever date are the same, Today button is displaying as expected. Can anyone please help me find the reason for this issue?

```
$("#val_effective_date").datepicker({
    showOn: 'both',
    dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy',
    buttonImage: glSiteName + '/Content/Images/Icons/Calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: 'clear',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altFormat: 'yymm',
    minDate: new Date($("#createdDate").val()),
    maxDate: new Date(9999, 12, 31),
    beforeShow: function (ele, obj) {
        HideDatePickerCloseButton();
        if ($("#SelectedRecord_ID").val() != '-1') {
            if (!confirm('Are you sure you wish to make this change?')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (y, m, i) {
        HideDatePickerCloseButton();
        var d = i.selectedDay;
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(y, m - 1, OnMonthYearChangeDateCheck(d, m - 1, y)));
        $('#val_effective_date').prop('title', $('#val_effective_date').val());
        if (inputsChanged == false) {
            SetInputsChange();
        }
    }
});

function HideDatePickerCloseButton() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-close").hide();
    }, 50);
}
```

**Button Markup:**

```
<div class="ui-datepicker-buttonpane ui-widget-content">
<button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all" data-handler="hide" data-event="click" style="display: none;">clear
</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide jsFiddle or a runnable code snippet? It's hard to see what it is you're asking.

Comment: Please find the jsFiddler sample in the below location: http://jsfiddle.net/dthota/pe9qefgL/     .   Initially, click on the datepicker textbox, calendar control will open with Today button. Then change your local system date to previous date and try to click on the datepicker textbox, Today button will not appear.

Comment: did you check the console? You're getting an error because `OnMonthYearChangeDateCheck` is not defined

Comment: But it sounds like the reason the Today button isn't showing is because "today" is before the minimum date. You've set the `minDate` as today, then changed today to be yesterday. You would see the same thing if you said `minDate: tomorrow`, where `tomorrow` is a variable containing tomorrow's date.

Comment: I have now corrected the console error. Thanks for pointing out the error. I got your point regarding the mindate and calendar control. If I try to rerun the sample after the system date was changed, calendar is opening as expected without any issues. How can we handle this situation? Client is trying to modify the system date after the page is loaded for some testing and raising this as a concern.